# eclipse rcp : how to use virtual table?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I just created a TableViewer with SWT.VIRTUAL, is this enough ?

How can I check whether TableItem is lazily created ?

I am using eclipse 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know you can find on [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#table), precisely [VIRTUAL table with lazy load](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet144.java?view=co) and [VIRTUAL table with lazy load with page size](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet201.java?view=co)..